# Given $X \sim Pois(\lambda)$, is the MLE of $P(X=3)$ consistent?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Given $X \sim Pois(\lambda)$, is the MLE of $P(X=3)$ consistent?

I've defined $z = P(X=3)$, and thus
$$
\hat{z}_{MLE} = \hat{P(X=3)}
= \hat{\frac{\lambda^3e^\lambda}{3!}}
= \frac{(\hat{\lambda}_{MLE})^3e^{(\hat{\lambda}_{MLE})}}{3!}
= \frac{\bar{X}^3e^{\bar{X}}}{3!}
$$

But how can I proceed from here? I know that
$$
MSE(\hat{z}_{MLE}, z)
= Var(\hat{z}_{MLE}) + Bias(\hat{z}_{MLE}, z)^2
$$
If I can show that the limit of that is 0 when $n$ goes to $\infty$ that'll prove what I want, but I can't seem to understand how to derive it.

Is it the only way to prove $\hat{z}_{MLE} = \hat{P(X=3)}$ is consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the MSE convergence criteria is not the best approach in such problems as mostly you will not be able to find a closed analytical form for the estimator's distribution. Therefore, just use the WLLN and the continuous mapping theorem (and Slutsky, if required). In your case $$
g(x) = \frac{x^3 e^{-3x}}{3!}
$$
is everywhere continuous transformation, thus you have that 
$$
g(\bar{X}_n)\xrightarrow{p} g(\mathbb{E}[X]=\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^3e^{-3\lambda}} {{3!}} = P(X=3).
$$

Comment: Pretty simple, thanks.